# How to omit attribute name when creating a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have a "many to many" relationship between group and user, and I need to create a checkbox tag to put users in a group. So I tried to use `fields_for` for that. Like that:

```
# ...
- users.each do |user|
  f.fields_for "group[user_ids][]", user.group_users.build do |group_user_f|
    = group_user_f.check_box :user_id, {}, user.id, false
```

And the Rails produces:

```
<input checked="checked" id="group_user_ids__user_id" name="group[user_ids][][user_id]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

But I need:

```
<input checked="checked" id="group_user_ids" name="group[user_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Without `[user_id]`.

I can manually with `check_box_tag`, but I prefer like above, using `fields_for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with just:

```
= f.check_box :user_ids, **{multiple: true}**, user.id, false
```

I didn't know that the plural of an attribute it's also an attribute for use in an association.